# Anime from 1987 about a boy leaving Earth

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching an anime TV show around 1987.

A boy and a woman (a android?) were on a ship leaving Earth and she said

> "Look at it one last time, because it will be the last time you look at it with human eyes"

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 12):

This is quite a long shot, but the anime you saw could be [*"Galaxy Express 999"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Express_999) (either the first episode of the series, or the compilation movie). The series first aired in Japan from 1978 to 1981, with the movie being released later that same year, so your watching a dubbed version in 1987 would fit.

The story starts on Earth, with a poor kid called Tetsuro and his mother trying to embark on the space train Galaxy Express 999 to reach a far planet, where - it is said - they would be given a machine body for free and they will be able to live forever.
However, the mother is killed by criminals before they can embark; Tetsuro is saved by a mysterious woman, Maetel, that offers him the chance to travel with her on the space train.
All of this happens in the first episode of the series, which then follows the route of the space train and the adventures the characters have in the locations they stop at.

The end of the episode contains these lines;

> "Take a good look at this scenery. The next time you see it, it might not be with human eyes"